# Django: get most frequent objects in many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-orm, django-related-manager

```
class SoundItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SoundCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SoundItemReview(models.Model):
    sound = models.ForeignKey(SoundItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sound_reviews')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(SoundCategory, related_name="sound_reviews")
```

For one instance of sound item (s), I can get its reviews with `s.sound_reviews.all()`, but how I count most frequent categories in its reviews (without having to manually iterate reviews and count categories)?

```
Eg for s there are 2 reviews:
review1: category1, category2
review2: category2, category3
then I want to get {"category2": 2, "category1": 1, "category3": 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an order the `SoundCategory`s by the number of items:

```
from django.db.models import Count

SoundCategory.objects.alias(nitem=Count('sound_reviews')).order_by('-nitem')
```

or when related to a single `SoundItem` item:

```
from django.db.models import Count

SoundCategory.objects.filter(sound_reviews__sound=my_sound_item).alias(
    nitem=Count('sound_reviews')
).order_by('-nitem')
```

Comment: As I mentioned, for one instance of sound item, not overall statistics, plz

Comment: sent an improvement edit: annotate will allow to extract nitem later

Comment: @JediKnight: `.annotate(..)` will repeat the aggregate in the select and is therefore a more expensive query. If you do not need the field, it is better to use `.alias(..)` if you somehow need it, `.annotate(..)` is of course better than counting each iteration.